# Call to MemcacheService.get() in LifecycleManager.ShutdownHook.shutdown() causes InterruptedException to be thrown

Tags: java, google-app-engine, caching, concurrency, memcached

I'm developing simple survey service. I collect statistics in [backend instance](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html) and dump them into [datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) every hour. I registered shutdown hook for my backend instance so that data collected within last hour is not lost. I also use cache to store some of my data.

Strangely call to [MemcacheService.get()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) in [LifecycleManager.ShutdownHook.shutdown()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/LifecycleManager.html#setShutdownHook%28com.google.appengine.api.LifecycleManager.ShutdownHook%29) causes [InterruptedException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) to be thrown. Here is full call-stack I have:

```
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Unexpected failure
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.getAll(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:59)
    at HitsHelper$LifetimeStats.getCachedStats(HitsHelper.java:51)
    at HitsHelper$LifetimeStats.update(HitsHelper.java:28)
    at HitsHelper.shutdown(HitsHelper.java:271)
    at com.google.appengine.api.LifecycleManager.beginShutdown(LifecycleManager.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServers$ServerWrapper.triggerLifecycleShutdownHook(BackendServers.java:890)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServers$ServerWrapper.shutdown(BackendServers.java:796)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServers.stopBackend(BackendServers.java:242)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ServersServlet$1.run(ServersServlet.java:97)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ServersServlet.doPost(ServersServlet.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:91)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$PrivilegedApiAction$1.get(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$PrivilegedApiAction$1.get(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:41)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:74)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:27)
    ... 46 more
```

Is there workaround for this ? I really need to update cache before my instance dies.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I had LifecycleManager.interruptAllRequests() at the beginning of my shutdown() method. It was putting all threads into interrupted state. That was the cause of exception.

Answer (score 0):

RPC calls made during shutdown are likely to be interrupted, as you're observing. You shouldn't rely on your shutdown handler being called to persist vital data - you should be doing this on a per-request basis.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it on a per-request basis because I'd hit limit of 5 writes per entity group. That's why I decided  to "buffer" data in backend instance in the first place. Plus I can write to datastore without any issues. It's RPC call too.

I'm ok with loosing data for last hour if Google has to kill my instance immediately but according to documentation I have 30 seconds until instance dies. I'd like to use that time.

Comment: @ruslan There are many ways around that, such as writing to a separate entity group and enqueueing tasks that 'roll up' recent updates into the main entity.

Comment: I just realized that I have LifecycleManager.interruptAllRequests() at the beginning of my shutdown() method. It was putting all threads into interrupted state. Unfortunately I can't answer my own question so I guess it will hang forever :(

Comment: @ruslan You can answer your own question, you'll just have to wait a while before you can do so.